# Send form query results to JSON API

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have some user-specific queries that show options in the browsable API's edit forms; these find options the currently logged in user has access to for creates and updates, and they show in both single- and multi-select fields. For example, a `detail` request will also show an `update` form populated with just the entities that user can apply.

How can I get these same query results to show through the JSON API?

More specifically, I'm using a `ModelViewSet` registered with a `DefaultRouter`, and here are a few code snippets to hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
class OrganizationInviteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ['create', 'update']:
            return OrganizationInviteStoreSerializer
        elif self.action == 'partial_update':
            return OrganizationInviteAcceptSerializer
        else:
            return OrganizationInviteDetailSerializer
```

```
class OrganizationInviteStoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = OrganizationInviteeSerializer(many=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrganizationInvite
```

```
class OrganizationInviteeSerializer(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.context.get('request').user
        return ...[logged-in user specific queryset here]...
```

The edit form that shows in an OrganizationInvite detail view has a dropdown that includes the queryset from the OrganizationInviteeSerializer; that shows with a GET query when viewing the browsable API, how (and what are the best practices) do I get this filtered data showing in my JSON output as well?

Answer (score 0):

Serializers allow complex data such as querysets and model instances to be converted to native Python datatypes that can then be easily rendered into JSON, XML, or other content types.
Link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

you can use `to_representations` in the serializer to pass extra data in JSON form.
**Example:**

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super().to_representation(instance)

    # Further logic and implementation come here

    return data
```